# Date format in android development

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to format a date from a string but is not working for me. This is my could anyone please check whether there is something wrong with it. Thank you

```
String edate = "23/04/2016";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE, d MMM yyyy ", Locale.UK);

        try {
            Date trydate = dateFormat.parse(edate);

            System.out.println("Try "+ trydate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

j

Comment: What made you choose this particular format string?

Comment: Date String and SimpleDateFormat should in the same form: `dd/MM/YYYY`

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",  Locale.UK); // here set the pattern as you date in string was containing like  date/month/year
         Date date = dateFormat.parse(edate);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                 //Be sure to catch the exception!
        }
```

In this format you wouldnt be getting time though>

Answer (score 0):

Look the API :SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale) ;

May be the locale cann't parse the edate that you give, if you  change the value of edate like "Fri, 02-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT",it will works well;
Here is the code:

public class DateFormat {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String dateStr = "Fri, 02-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT";  
    String pattern = "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z";  
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US); 
    try {
        Date t=format.parse(dateStr);
        System.err.println(t);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}